# Preg Replace Issue is stripping numbers/character length?

Tags: php

Consider the following example....

The issue is with the preg_replace which is used to replace the variables total_balance_overriden and total_balance.

```
$text = 'this: {{total_balance_overridden}} - that: {{total_balance}}';

$total = '$517.50';
$overiddentotal = '$390.00';

$text = preg_replace('/{{total_balance_overridden}}/', $overiddentotal, $text);
$text = preg_replace('/{{total_balance}}/', $total, $text);


    echo $total;

    echo $overiddentotal;

    echo $text;
```

This gives me...

```
$517.50

$390.00

this: 0.00 - that: 7.50
```

It appears that the $total and $overiddentotal vars have the correct output, but when they have been replaced using the preg_replace, their length has been stripped, and the currency sign and first two numbers are missing. Any ideas why?

Note: If i replace the dollar sign with a pound sign it works! I get...

```
this: £390.00 - that: £517.50
```

So is the dollar sign and 2 numbers some sort of special character or var thats getting stripped?

Comment: You dont need regex here, just `$text = str_replace(['{{total_balance_overridden}}', '{{total_balance}}'], [$overiddentotal, $total], $text);`

Comment: $ with following digits is special code - reference to match group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dollar signs are special characters in replacement strings, they normally refer to captured substrings from the match. If you want a literal dollar sign, you have to escape it:

```
$total = '\$517.50';
$overiddentotal = '\$390.00';
```

Note also, in this case, there's no need for regex at all. Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and you won't have this issue.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you, str_replace is much simpler!